# grunt understand task scripts and php

Tags: php, gruntjs, task, target, watch

i use this guntfile.js and work fine for my project, but i don't understand some things.

```
'use strict';

var     bsoptions={
//porta di lavoro del livereload standard 
port: 35729,
//path del nostro tema
themepath: "wp-content/themes/rttheme18",
//host inserito nell'installazione di wp
http_host: "www.bottonisworld.localhost"} ;
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
// inseriamo la configurazione di grunt
grunt.initConfig({
    //carichiamo il file json 
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    //banner inseribile nei file nel caso di concat plugin ad esempio
    banner: "Nome pacchetto <%= pkg.name %>",
    //proprietà custom per mostrare il loro utilizzo nei task successivi con la sintassi di grunt engine
    BSbasePath: bsoptions.themepath,
    BSHTTP_HOST: bsoptions.http_host,
    //____________ task "watch" _________
    watch: {
        // dichiariamo quali file deve guardare watch
        scripts:{
            files:[
                '<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.html',
        '<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.css','<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}']},
php: {
            files: ['<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.php']
        },
        //opzioni del task watch
        options: {
            //usiamo il livereload
            livereload: true,
            //inseriamo il keepalive
            keepalive:true,
            spawn: false
        }
    }
});
//loading dei plugin necessari al nostro lavoro
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-livereload');
//registrazione del task di lavoro che esegue ogni singolo task
grunt.registerTask('default', function() {
grunt.task.run([
    'watch'
]);
});
};
```

I want undestand "**scripts**" and "**php**" task. I have searched in google but did not find anything, someone can explain me or tell me where to find documentation of these tasks / target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file contains a function which has initialization variables in the JSON format.
See  http://www.w3schools.com/json/
and JSON wildcards at
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

**Scripts:** This includes all files which conform to the given pattern "/**/*.html" under your BSbasePath variable.

```
   scripts:{
        files:[
            '<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.html',
            '<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.css',
            '<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
   },
```

**PHP:** this includes all the files under the starting path BSbasePath which conform to the pattern /**/*.php. These are all files which have the endings '.html', '.css', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.webp', '.svg'.

```
   php: {
        files: ['<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.php']
    },
```

The asterisk * means for any characters and numbers, even special characters. This means that all files will be read in and compared with the wildcards. Only the matching files will be used. These will be the files which have a '.php' at the end of their names.

[The description for the configuration is here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks)

Comment: correct,
but I would like to know where to find the documentation of the task "script" and "php".If I want to use "asp" file I must declare:

   asp: {
        files: ['<%= BSbasePath %>/**/*.asp']
    }

If is yes, where is the documentation??? :(

Comment: You have an example here http://scotch.io/bar-talk/a-simple-guide-to-getting-started-with-grunt

The names 'scripts' and 'php' are just names chosen. I think that it does not matter how you name it. Grant will take them and work on these files. Grant collects those files. It just makes sense to name the files which are needed by Javascript 'scripts' and the files for PHP execution are called 'php'.